# disable submit button without grey out effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

How do I disable an HTML form submit button without it being greyed out?

The problem: I want to grey out an entire form, and having the submit button grey out before the rest of the form does looks silly.

```
$("#postform").submit(function() {
      //disable submit button
      $("#submitPF").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      //blur form
      $("#postform").animate({opacity: 0.4},250);
      $.post("/POST.php", $("#postform").serialize(),function() {
         //free submit button
         $("#submitPF").removeAttr("disabled");
         //unblur
         $("#postform").animate({opacity: 1},500);
      });
      return false;
   });
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override greyed out effect of element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539460/override-greyed-out-effect-of-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just hijack the button

```
$("#submitPF").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

you can style the `disabled` version with css.

`input:disabled`

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is for it to not be clickable you could always make a mask layer to go over it.  Perhaps a white bg that fades from 0 opacity to 20% opacity.  Any clicking on the submit button will not work because of the mask layer in front of it.