# Override greyed out effect of element

Tags: jquery

I have this line of jQuery which disables all buttons once an event has been triggered.

```
$("button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Disabled buttons are greyed-out by default, but I was wondering if there was a way to override this behaviour so that the buttons are disabled, but with no indication to the user?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: It's for a game. The buttons are answer fields and change colour to indicate the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Via CSS:

One solution is to set the same style for disabled and enabled buttons using the `button[disabled]` css selector like this:

```
button[disabled], button{
        color:#fff;
        border: none;
        background-color: grey;
    }
```

The problem is that browsers have different styles for buttons by default, so you will need to style your buttons.

#### Via Jquery:

Another solution is to remove the click event handler to the buttons, so replace this line:

```
$("button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

for this one:

```
$('button').off('click');
```

To enable the click event again use:

```
$('button').on('click');
```

More info about add/remove events handler on this good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/210345/670377) at SO

**Note:** You should add id for the buttons (if you are using more than one) because the code above will remove the click on all your buttons.

Comment: Thanks Tom :) 
I couldn't get 
    $('button').off('click');
working, but while researching your answer, came across... 
    $('button').attr('onclick','').unbind('click');
which seems to do the job.

Comment: and yes, you can use bind/unbind for versions of Jquery before < 1.7 ;)